# Get correct ID from loop

Tags: jquery, dictionary

I have a `foreach` that prints the data from my database in PHP. I got a link for every of these rows that allow me to delete each data from database. Right under `foreach` I got a `input type="hidden"` with the ID of the data as value.

```
<?php
    foreach($sql->query("SELECT * FROM table") AS $row) {
        <input type="hidden" value="'.(int)$row['id'].'">
        echo $row['name'].' (<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="delete-row">delete</a>)';
    }
?>
```

After some intense Google searches I came up with this. But when I click on the "delete" link it prints every single row in the loop with this code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#delete-row').click(function() {
        var val = $('input[type="hidden"]').map(function() {
            return this.value;
        }).get();

        alert(val);
    });
});
```

This is wrong! I want to get the ID for that link I click on. If I click on the link with ID 3 it shall alert me with ID 3. Do you know how I can fix my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is your `<input type="hidden"...` being printed? Your PHP code looks like it might throw an error.

Comment: You're asking a javascript question, please post the rendered HTML as the PHP isn't worth much here. Also agree with greener about your hidden input not being rendered.

Comment: You are using duplicate ID's. your click event will only get bound to the first link. Fix it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not even use a hidden field for this.

```
<?php
    foreach($sql->query("SELECT * FROM table") AS $row) {
        echo $row['name'].' (<a href="javascript:void(0)" data=". (int)$row['id'] ." class="delete-row">delete</a>)';
    }
?>


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.delete-row').click(function() {
        var val = $(this).attr('data');    
        alert(val);
    });
});
```

Comment: Id's are unique. You're using id="delete-row for every element. You need to give them a different ID. Use a class instead.

Comment: Thanks ComputerArts. Its a shame I could not pick it up. Too busy to get some reputation!!!! :-) Modified my code as per the advise from ComputerArts.